# jQuery Gallery Plugin with Vertical Thumbnails

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Looking for a jQuery gallery plugin similar to Galleria or GalleryView but instead of the thumbnail images on the bottom they located on the left or right vertically. Thumbnails also need to have a scroller as well, ie show 5 thumbsnails at a time but can page back and forth to see more thumbnails.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, galleryview 2.1.1 has vertical thumbnails feature, check it out http://plugins.jquery.com/node/13734